# If I use Delegates, I need those methods to be static?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a C# code like this:

```
using System;
delegate int anto(int x);
class Anto 
{
    static void Main()
    {
        anto a = square;
        int result = a(3);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    static int square(int x)
    {
        return x*x;
    }
}
```

which output's : `9`. Well I'm a novice in C#, so I started to play around with this code and so when I remove the `static` keyword from the `square` method, then I'm getting error like this:

```
An object reference is required to access non-static member `Anto.square(int)'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

what causes this error? So if I use `delegates` I need the method to be `static`?

I run this code [here](http://ideone.com/9Y81q)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Main` is static, it can only reference other static members.  If you remove `static` from `square`, it becomes an instance member, and in the `static` context of `Main`, there is no instance of any object, so instance members aren't 'valid'.

Thankfully there's nothing crazy going on with delegates, it's just the way `static` works - it indicates members are global to a type and not an instance of that type.

Answer (score 3):

It's required to be static because it's used in a static method.  You'd need an instance of `Anto` to make your example work.

```
var myAnto = new Anto();
anto a = myAnto.square;
```

This is untested and may not compile based on the protection level of `Anto.square`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't *need* to be static. You can assign a non-static method to a delegate, but if it is non-static then you need to instatiate an object of type `Anto`:

```
Anto anto = new Anto();
anto a = anto.square;
```

It's rather pointless here though since the method doesn't access any of the instance members. It makes more sense that it is static.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods may be called from before creating an instance, you must be a static method.

Can be written as follows, if necessary

```
anto a = (x)=>x*x ;
```